# StatusBar Style updates with some delay

Tags: swift, statusbar, ios-statusbar

I have 2 `StoryBoard` in my project and all `ViewController` in my 1st `storyBoard` are of `.lightContent` `statusBarStyle` and all `ViewController` in my 2nd `storyBoard` are of `.default` `statusBarStyle`.

For that i have done below steps.

1.`View controller-based status bar appearance` is **`true`**

2 Already use below code.

```
extension UINavigationController {
    open override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
       return topViewController?.preferredStatusBarStyle ?? .default
    }
}
```

When i set 2nd `storyBoard` `ViewController` as rootController from 1st `storyBoard` statusBar style changing but i am facing below issue.

When i set 1st storyBoard `ViewController` as rootController, statusBarStyle update after few seconds.

## Not Proper

[image]

## After Few Seconds

[image]

here is my demo link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/ijqg73zm1jxbokc/statusBarDemo.zip?dl=0

## UPDATE

**MY First ViewController Code**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .default
}

@IBAction func btnInitialControllerTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Initial", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InitialViewController") as! InitialViewController
    let navController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: controller)
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = navController
}
```

**MY Second ViewController Code**

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}

@IBAction func btnControllerTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
}
```

Please guide me what i'm missing or what i have implemented wrongly.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: please share the code how are you switching view controllers between both storyboards? Are using `DispatchQueue.main.async` ?

Comment: @S1LENTWARRIOR, Already put the link of my demo code in Question.

Comment: the thing is that everyone doesn't have enough time to look at the whole code and find the exact code, therefore it is better to share the code snippet related to the question that you're asking :)

Comment: @S1LENTWARRIOR, question updated.

Answer (score 1):

**InitialViewController:**

```
var status = true
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return status ? .lightContent : .default
}

@IBAction func btnControllerTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    self.status = false
    self.preferredStatusBarStyle
    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
}
```

> I found a solution like this. It works well but I don't know how
>   useful it is.I just think it's better to change it without go on the other screen.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This works, but in my app this code will execute from all ViesController if token is expired so for this i have to put this code in every controller. is there any global solution for that?

Comment: I didn't find any solutions for that

Comment: @Kuldeep its a separate question that how to run a code in all view controllers, and it also has its own solutions. If the above answer solves the problem asked in the question, then you should accept this answer and upvote it. Trust me it won't cost you anything ;)